# How to test if a directory already exist in PHP?

Tags: php, directory

How can i test if a directory already exist and if not create one in PHP?

Comment: PS: is_dir doesnt work for me:

Comment: why is_dir doesnt work for you?

Comment: What error do you get when you use `is_dir`?

Comment: I got no errors and the dir isnt created

Comment: is_dir() just checks to see if a path passed to it as a parameter is a directory. You need mkdir() to actually make the directory.

Comment: is_dir only check if the path is a directory, doesnt create it. mkdir() does!  @ john: just 10 seconds earlier!! ;)

Comment: @streetparade: is_dir doesn't create a directory, it just tests to see if the directory exists and if it is a directory.  Try mkdir ( http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php ) to create a directory.

Comment: I know ok i forgot to set mkdir to true like this mkdir($mydir,0655,true);

Comment: @DaNieL, great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filename = "/tmp";
if (!file_exists($filename))
    echo $filename, " does not exist";
elseif (!is_dir($filename))
    echo $filename, " is not a directory";
else
    echo "Directory ", $filename, " already exists";
```

`file_exists` checks if the path/file exists and `is_dir` checks whether the given filename is a directory.

**Edit:**

to create the directory afterwards, call

```
mkdir($filename);
```

Comment: The call to file_exists(...) is not necessary.  is_dir(...) will return false if it does not exist.

Comment: I would say the same, but he said 'is_dir doesnt work for me'

Comment: `file_exists` should be called anyway if the next step is to create a directory with the given name. If there was a file named exactly like the target directory, a call to `mkdir` would fail although the "directory" was not there...

Comment: Yeah unfortunatly but i dont know why is_dir doesnt work i got no errors nothing nmnor the dir is created

Comment: @Mike:  True, but this way you know which condition (doesn't exist or isn't a directory) led to the false return value.

Comment: i forgot to set mkdir to true like this mkdir($mydir,0655,true);

Comment: @streetparade:  Have you tried running this from the command line?  If you're running via the web, have you checked the web server error logs?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer above based on the questioner's comments:

```
$filename = "/tmp";
if (!is_dir($filename)) {
    mkdir($filename);
}
```

You need to use `mkdir()` to actually make the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dir = "/path/to/dir";
if(is_dir($dir) == false)
    mkdir($dir);
```

If you want the complete path the be created (if not present), set recusive parameter to true.

See [documentation of mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

if(file_exists("Directory path") && is_dir("Directory path"))
{

//Your Code;

}